# Angular Material: Mat-tab-group takes more place as it needs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've added the mat-tab-group with two mat-tabs to my Angular-component (Popup). Now the mat-tab-group takes more place as it needs. Around 10-20px are unused but used by this material component (says the browser console: https://ibb.co/b3Q13zj).

You can see it on this picture: https://ibb.co/q1xkt3t

I've tried lots of things but I can't find out where this is coming from... and how I can solve it.

Comment: please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: I can't share a minimal reproducible code because the online angular editors always run into errors... is it a usual behaviour of the mat-tab-group?